# How to devide sum groups from one column by another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Suppose I have this table I want to query a person and the result  should be to get sum of numbers devided by country's total

```
Country  person  number

USA        A        3
USA        A        2
USA        C        2
RUS        B        1
RUS        C        3
IND        A        2
DEU        A        1
DEU        D        1
```

Suppose  I query person A
I want to get

```
USA 5/7
IND 2/2
DEU 1/2
```

SUM OF NUMBER / SUM OF COUNTRY
for person A

Now suppose  I want to complicate things even  further.. suppose  I have a month column I want to get for each month these results

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation and `/`:

```
select country,
       sum(case when person = 'A' then number else 0 end) / sum(number)
from t
group by country;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=192c1425445c4492673034b9abc3ed09)**

```
select country, person, sum(number) sum_of_number,
(select sum(number) from t t1 where t.country=t1.country) sum_of_country
from t
where person='A'
group by country, person
```

Comment: How does this answer  the question?